# Vector bundles on $\mathbf{P}^1$ and the Iwasawa decomposition

Tags: vector-bundles, adeles

As everyone knows, every vector bundle on $\mathbf{P}^1$  splits as a direct sum of line bundles $\mathcal{O}(a_1)\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathcal{O}(a_n)$. This means that in the Weil-uniformisation description of vector bundles
$$\text{Bun}_{\text{GL}_n}(\mathbf{P}^1)\ =\ \text{GL}_n(k(\mathbf{P}^1))\backslash \text{GL}_n(\mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{P}^1})/\text{GL}_n(\mathbf{O}_{\mathbf{P}^1})$$
the diagonal matrices $\text{diag}(t^{a_1},...,t^{a_n})$ form a complete set of double coset representatives, where $t$ is a uniformiser of some point in $\mathbf{P}^1$.

**Question:** Pretending that we knew nothing about vector bundles on $\mathbf{P}^1$, is it possible to get this result on double quotient representatives directly using the Iwasawa decomposition of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{P}^1})$, or something similar?

---

**Clarification:** The question is “the right side is confusing, how can we massage it algebraically to make it obvious that it's just $\mathbf{Z}$"? I really love David Speyer's answer, a (different, non-adelic) way to compute $\text{Bun}_{\text{GL}_n}(\mathbf{P}^1)$, but it doesn't address that confusion. In my mind the **question is still open**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am not fully confident in my understanding of the terminology here. Corrections are welcome.

$\def\GL{\mathrm{GL}}\def\PP{\mathbb{P}}\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}\def\Spec{\mathrm{Spec}\ }$My understanding is that this is Bruhat decomposition for the loop group of $\GL_n$.

Rather than your adelic formalism, I will cover $\PP^1$ with two open sets $\Spec \CC[t]$ and $\Spec \CC[t^{-1}]$, overlapping in $\Spec \CC[t, t^{-1}]$. Since every projective module over $\CC[t]$ is free, any vector bundle trivializes one each of our open sets (and hence on their overlap), and so vector bundles are classified by double cosets
$$\GL_n(\CC[t]) \backslash \! \GL_n(\CC[t, t^{-1}]) / \GL_n(\CC[t^{-1}]).$$

Now (I might be using terminology wrongly here) the ind-group $\GL_n(\CC[t, t^{-1}]$ is a Kac-Moody group, called the loop group of $\GL_n$. A pair of opposite Borels can be taken to be
$$B_- := \{ g \in \GL_n(\CC[t]) : g \bmod t \ \mbox{is upper triangular} \}$$
$$B_+ := \{ g \in \GL_n(\CC[t^{-1}]) : g \bmod t^{-1} \ \mbox{is lower triangular} \}.$$
The Weyl group is $W:=S_n \ltimes \mathbb{Z}^n$, and can be represented by permutation matrices whose nonzero entries are monomials in $t$. We have Bruhat decomposition, $\GL_n(\CC[t, t^{-1}] = \bigsqcup_{w \in W} B_- w B_+$. So the elements of $W$ are double coset representatives for $B_- \backslash \GL_n(\CC[t,t^{-1}])/B_+$.

We want to quotient not by the Borels but by the parabolics, $P_- := \GL_n(\CC[t])$ and $P_+ = \GL_n(\CC[t^{-1}])$. So the elements of $W$ still represent all cosets, but redundantly. More specifically, the parabolic subgroup $W_P$ of $W$ corresponding to $P_{\pm}$ is $S_n$. Standard theory tells us that we can get a family of representatives for $B_- \backslash \GL_n(\CC[t,t^{-1}])/B_+$ by taking representatives for $W_P \backslash W / W_P$.

We compute $$W_P \backslash W / W_P = S_n \backslash (S_n \ltimes \ZZ^n) / S_n = S_n \backslash \ZZ^n$$
$$ = \{ (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) \in \ZZ^n : a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \cdots \geq a_n \}.$$
Thus, isomorphism classes of vector bundles are indexed by $n$-tuples of decreasing integers, which is correct.

Comment: Are your Borels and parabolics really what you mean?  Your $P_-$ contains $B_-$, but your $P_+$ does not contain $B_+$.  (If there's a typo and you edit, note that some of your $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C[t, t^{-1}])$s are missing the closing parenthesis.  Also, as a TeX note, `\operatorname{Spec}` rather than `\mathrm{Spec}\ `will take care of the spacing for you.)

Comment: @LSpice Fixed $P_+$, thanks! I think the others are right (well, it probably would have been better nomenclature to switch which was $+$ and which was $-$, but I think it is logically consistent now, and I don't want to risk making new typos).

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting way of computing $\text{Bun}(\mathbf{P}^1)$. However I don't think it answers my question: I'm genuinely interested in undestanding that adelic double quotient and I think this answer, while pretty, “cheats" by importing extra geometric information to bypass the adelic quotient entirely.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know an adelic way to think about this, but I'm sure there are many other answerers who do. It seems to me that most computations I've done with adeles start by noticing some PID subring of the field which can be used to make the computation more finite, so this doesn't seem unusual to me.